# Movie or tv show with robots disguised as childen who try to kill progatonist

Tags: story-identification, movie

Long ago, probably during the previous millennium, I saw part of a movie or tv show on television at least one time.

The protagonist had problems with robots disguised as specific humans who were part of some alien or demonic plot to take over the world.  Their eyes glowed when they attacked the protagonist.

The only part of the film I remember seeing from all those years ago was the end, when the protagonist was attacked in an isolated farm by a father and two kids, all robots in disguise, but managed to defeat them.

I remember that the "boy" robot was impersonating a boy named Christopher (who no doubt had been abducted or killed by the killer robots) and was portrayed by an actor named Christopher Johnson or similar last name.

So can anyone identify this movie or tv show?

Comment: the theme of dangerous children shows up a lot. star trek, village of the damned, it's alive. we all know that kids are sociopaths often.

Comment: Seeing how fast you answered it, did you create the question only to answer it?

Answer (score 3):

To answer my own quesiton the film is *Annihilator*, a tv movie shown by NBC on April 7, 1986, which was an unsold pilot for a television series.

Yesterday this question [https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/237578/movie-with-killer-androids-glowing-eyes-screaming[1]](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/237578/movie-with-killer-androids-glowing-eyes-screaming%5B1%5D) described a somewhat familiar plot, and I wondered whether the answer given, *Annihilator*, could be the movie or show I remembered with the killer robot kids attacking at a farm.

And I found and watched *Annihilator* on the internet, and it turned out that was it, and I finally learned what had led to the confrontation at the farm.

Nicole Eggert was born January 13, 1972, and so was 14 years, 2 months, and 25 days old when *Annihilator* was broadcast, and so was probably 13 when she portrayed the killer robot disguised as Elyse Jeffries.  The real Elyse Jeffries must have been abducted or killed by the killer robots.

And the end credits listed Christopher Johnson as Christopher Jeffries.  So my memory is confirmed.

But the IMDB full cast and crew list for *Annihilator* (1986 TV MOvie) dosn't list Christopher Johnson or any variation on the name, nor any character named Christopher or Christopher Jeffries, which is a puzzling omission.

[https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0090649/fullcredits?ref_=tt_cl_sm#cast[2]](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0090649/fullcredits?ref_=tt_cl_sm#cast%5B2%5D)

Anyway, if someone is interested in movies and television about alien invasions, or robot revolts, or with "evil kids", or with "Glowing Eyes of doom"

[https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/GlowingEyesOfDoom[4]](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/GlowingEyesOfDoom%5B4%5D)

*Annihilator* is one they should be interested in.