# Old sci fi movie where alien robots take over human form

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens, robots

Sci fi low budget movie from the 1970s, '80s, or '90s where alien robots take over human form. The only way to see the aliens is to burn them because they have black skeletons.

The movie started with a car chase.
Also, the name was something like "Terminators". In one famous scene I remember, the lead actor runs his car into a lady and she burns, revealing a black plastic shopping bag robot like face with full human like eyes and a skeleton, but the skeleton is a black color.  I found the movie on YouTube five years ago, but don't remember the name

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Are you sure the robots are alien? Because you didn't mention anything about a spaceship or other planets.

Comment: Found it my self it is TV movie Annihilator 1986

Comment: If anyone posts a correct answer, please consider marking it as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer), which you can do by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons. It's this site's way of formally indicating that a query has been solved to the querent's satisfaction.

Answer (score 12):

Is this ***[Annihilator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annihilator_(film))*** (1986)...?

> A newspaper reporter, Robert Armour, is in a romantic relationship with another reporter, Angela Taylor. Angela, along with her friend, Cindy (a photographer for the paper) take a flight to Hawaii. When Angela and Cindy return from the vacation, they act strangely, causing Robert to be concerned, and the women turn out to be androids who try to kill Robert. An alien force planning on taking over the world caused Flight 508 to disappear; they abducted the human passengers and replaced them with identical-looking androids. Robert now becomes the hunter and hunted, knowing he must hunt down the androids.

- It's on YouTube.
- It's about the right age.
- The title is similar to "Terminators."
- The synopsis above fits the general premise you outlined.
- It begins with a car chase sequence.
- There's a sequence about 35 minutes into the runtime where a female robot leaps onto the front of a car a man is driving. He subsequently gets out of the car and repeatedly hits her in the face with a crowbar, breaking off pieces of her artificial skin and revealing a black skull beneath. He then sets her face alight, exposing even more of the black skull.

Comment: I note I asked a question about "The Annihilater" https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/237614/movie-or-tv-show-with-robots-disguised-as-childen-who-try-to-kill-progatonist/237615#237615