# Horror movie featuring a Terminator-like female cyborg as the antagonist

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror, cyborg

It was a sci-fi / horror with a female cyborg. Same era as *The Terminator*, say early '80s.

Started with a commercial flight disappearing from radar, then reappearing, and when landing, a female cyborg had joined the flight. She was definitely the villain.

I can't really remember what she was doing, but she was quite Terminator-like. Pretty sure the film ended with a fight-off in what looked like a farm shed with tools; there was fire and it was at night. Can anyone help name it?

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you actually watch this? Feel free to give a range or a decade rather than a precise year, but the more precise you can be, the better.

Comment: If the answer by Logic Dictates is correct, then the film would be the one asked about in  https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/237578/movie-with-killer-androids-glowing-eyes-screaming  and  https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/237614/movie-or-tv-show-with-robots-disguised-as-childen-who-try-to-kill-progatonist

Comment: 100% that film: Annihiliator 1986 thanks 

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Pretty sure this is the unsold TV-series pilot, ***[Annihilator](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0090649/)*** (1986).

From IMDB:

> Humanoid killer robots stalk a newspaperman who has knowledge of their existence. One of the robots is made to look like his girlfriend.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annihilator_(film)):

> *Annihilator* is a 1986 science fiction television film directed by Michael Chapman and starring Mark Lindsay Chapman, Catherine Mary Stewart, Susan Blakely and Lisa Blount. It was an unsold pilot for a potential TV series.

> A newspaper reporter, Robert Armour, is in a romantic relationship with another reporter, Angela. Angela, along with her friend, Cindy (a photographer for the paper) take a flight to Hawaii. **When Angela and Cindy return from the vacation, they act strangely, causing Robert to be concerned, and the women turn out to be androids who try to kill Robert. An alien force planning on taking over the world caused Flight 508 to disappear; they abducted the human passengers and replaced them with identical-looking androids.** Robert now becomes the hunter and hunted, knowing he must hunt down the androids.

At around the [20:36](https://youtu.be/Bsc4uBSNFtk?t=1236) mark in the video below, the protagonist, Robert, mentions that the commercial flight his girlfriend, Angela, was a passenger on disappeared from the radar screen for over an hour, then reappeared as if nothing had happened.

> ROBERT: After a week in Hawaii with Cindy, I knew Angela would need to get back to work, just to rest; I could count on that. What I didn't count on was how my life was about to change... completely. **The plane was late -- over an hour late -- and no one from the airlines had an explanation. They were nervous and covering up something, but they kept insisting everything was alright. It wasn't until later that I would learn that Flight 508 had simply disappeared from the radar screen, for over an hour... and then reappeared as though nothing had happened. But something had happened; something that would change everything.**

It later transpires that Angela and several others were replaced by killer androids. There's a nighttime showdown in a barn, at around the [1:19:01](https://youtu.be/Bsc4uBSNFtk?t=4741) mark, with the barn ultimately being destroyed in a fiery explosion.

Comment: Ah, the good old days of the 80s, when a plane being *a whole hour late* was considered suspicious!